# how to limit the number of "/" in a string

Tags: java, regex

How do I use lookahead assertion to limit by range the number of "/"

I have tired the following

> ^(?=/{1,3})$

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!(?:[^/]*/){4})
```

That basically means the string **cannot** contain 4 slashes.

This assumes you allow other characters between slashes, but a maximum of 3 slashes.

A positive version would be `^(?=[^/]*(?:/[^/]*){0,3}$)` or `^[^/]*(?:/[^/]*){0,3}$`, without the lookahead.
Of course, the problem is trivial without regular expressions, if possible.

Lets try to break that last one down:

- `^` - Start of the string.
- `[^/]*` - Some characters that are not slashes (or none)
- `(?: )` - A logical group. Similar to `()`, but does not capture the result (we do not need it after validation)
- `/[^/]*` - Slash, followed by non-slash characters.
- `{0,3}` - From 0 to 3 times.
- `$` - End of the string.

Comment: @seesee - I trust you can adapt the last pattern to your range `:)`

Comment: ^(?=[^/]*(?:/[^/]*){0,3}$) -> This does not work but ^[^/]*(?:/[^/]*){0,3}$ -> care to explain a bit? what is * and ?:, it looks complicated

Comment: [^/]* - Some characters that are not slashes (or none) -> I don't understand this part. and why the logical group is "/[^/]*"

Comment: For example, if our string is `abc/ef/g/hi`, the pattern matches the string in steps: `abc` `/ef` `/g` `/hi`.

Comment: =X I still don't understand. what does * actually do?

Comment: Oh. `*` matches zero or more, so `a*` matches ``, `a`, `aa`... I'd suggest you'd read something like this: http://xisb.wordpress.com/2012/05/09/what-absolutely-every-programmer-should-know-about-regular-expressions/ - it is informative, but not too much `:)`

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following (you have to say that there should be no / afterwards):

```
^(?=/{1,3}([^/]|$))
```